# Android Sharing on Facebook (SDK 4)

Tags: android, facebook

Trying to share an image with Facebook SDK 4.0 for android.

app.graddle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    // Facebook's library to implement Login with Facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.facebookshare" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int ACTION_PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    //Facebook client
    private CallbackManager fb_callbackManager;
    private ShareDialog fb_shareDialog;

    private Button button;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize Facebook API
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        fb_callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageView:
                loadImage();
                break;
            case R.id.button:
                share();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void loadImage(){
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("max-width", 170);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("max-height", 160);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY",1);

        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ACTION_PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == ACTION_PICK_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void share(){
        String shareText = editText.getText().toString();
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
            shareDialog.registerCallback(fb_callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Share Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "SHARE SUCCESS");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Share Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "SHARE CACELLED");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "Share: " + exception.getMessage());
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap())
                    .build();
            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(content);
        }

    }
}
```

Nothing is shown, or at least not visible, because I have to hit back to be able to interact with my activity again after trying to share on Facebook.

No DEBUG string is logged on Logcat. So I understand ShareDialog can show Photo content.

Could somebody post a simple working example of sharing image with Facebook for SDK 4.0(android)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an Internet Permission to your android manifest for sharing to work!

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application ...
</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

        manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

        manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new  FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
       {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                publishImage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
               System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception)
            {
                System.out.println("onError");
            }
        });
     }

     private void publishImage(){
         Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),     R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

         SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("Welcome To Facebook Photo Sharing on steroids!")
            .build();

         SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

         ShareApi.share(content, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,    Intent data)
     {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
       callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
     }
   }
```

This piece of code posts an image to Facebook wall. The thing you might want to do is use the share dialog; here I just share the image directly with a caption without using the share dialog.

Please let me know what you get! I have tested it to make sure it works.

Comment: True, I forgot to put it in the sample. I edited question. But still, that's not the problem.

Comment: I added sample code for you - it works when I try on my device.

Comment: Great! I made it work with your help. Only one thing... setCaption() is no longer available do I don't know how I could share a picture AND a text. And, definitely, using a ShareDialog would be much better. Anyway, your answer is correct and I mark it as such.

Comment: I am glad it worked. I will test out using share dialog later then let you know!

Comment: Oh! I did already. It does, what does not work is setting image caption. It's definitely not available anymore... Although I read somewhere it's a known issue and they're planning to solve it

Comment: Just upgraded to SDK 4.1.0, alredy available, and setCaption() is there!... but doesn't work :(

Comment: Mine worked with 4.1.0 and I even tested it by posting to my FB wall. when you say it does not work, do you mean after posting you do not see the caption?

Comment: That's it. I don't see the caption in the photo and it doesn't show in dialog when using ShareDialog either.

Comment: I think I know why: if you use the dialog - that means you let the user type some text and therefore the caption does not apply? What do you think?

Comment: You're right! It's a pity, but using ShareDialog caption is not set, it is using just ShareApi... I don't know which option I'll finally choose, because with ShareDialog I also get a Notification from Facebook... Anyway, you rock! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, trying to get this code to work, but what is "publish_actions"?  Is that something I need to replace with something else? Thanks.

Comment: publish_actions is a permission required when your app needs to post to user wall! You need it as is.

Comment: Hey, now i am using facebook sdk 4.6.0. still setCaption() is not working. Did you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're sharing links, images or video via the Facebook for Android app, you also need to declare the **FacebookContentProvider** in the **manifest**, like:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true" />
```

In above line # 1 you will see a number 1234, in `FacebookContentProvider1234`, you need to replace it with your Facebook app Id.

Comment: Thanks for your help @penguin, but I already did that. Not working.